# Bootstrap accordion only auto-collapsing one panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I've been scratching my head on this for the past 2 hours.  I have an accordion with two panels.  I want the first panel to be expanded by default.  When the collapsed panel's header is clicked, I want that panel to expand and the other to collapse.  It only works in certain situations for the second panel.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47n94/).

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="proposalAccordian" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#proposalAccordian" href="#collapseContact">Contact</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseContact" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.Partial("_ContactPanel")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#proposalAccordion" href="#collapseProposal">Proposal</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseProposal" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.Partial("_ProposalPanel")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap v3.1.1 and jQuery v1.10.4.

Comment: There's something wrong with the fiddle's resources. Here's your code in another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MMxMn/2/

Comment: The difference in your fiddle and mine seems to be that I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `data-parent="#proposalAccordian"`

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#proposalAccordian"  href="#collapseProposal">Proposal</a>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicos/JKqGc/

Comment: While you're correct in that there's an ID value mismatch in the code, it doesn't seem to affect the functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/47n94/3/

Comment: You have jQuery 1.11 in your fiddle. :-)

Comment: Here is your fiddle with v1.10. It doesn't work in Chrome or IE11. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/JKqGc/1/

Comment: Thanks man! I only recently joined Stack, try and help as much as i can!

Comment: Absolutely brutal.  A stupid typo!  Thanks for another set of eyes.

Comment: @Panoply can please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170352/one-open-panel-at-a-time-bootstrap4-accordion-in-angular4

Answer (score 0):

```
Strangely, your code works on jQuery 1.9.x:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MMxMn/5

```
and 1.11.x:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MMxMn/4

```
but not 1.10.x:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MMxMn/8

Note that I've normalized the spelling of "accordion" to fix the accordion functionality.

Comment: Not for me in Chrome or IE11. The page twitches as though I clicked an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    All panels inside this..
</div>
```

In our case, the problem was in HTML structure, as we had  inside foreach loop. The fix is to use a single accordion for all the panels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $collapse = $('.collapse');
$collapse.collapse().on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $collapse.collapse('hide');
});
```